Validation and reset parent and child functional component in react
I am transitioning from angular to react 18. I am currently self educating myself with basic CRUD operation. Everything is working fine but for some reason I am not sure why triggering validation and then resetting is failing.
Here is my parent component. I am using it for creating new item or updating existing item depending on what user chooses to do, add new item to the application or edit the existing data
            export default function FoodItemEntry() {
              const [newItemData, setNewItemData] = useState({
                uploadedImageList: [],
                itemAttributeList: [],   .........
              });
              const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
              const [validateChild, setValidateChild] = useState({
                uploadedImage: false,
                itemAttribute: false, .........
              });
              const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
              const [childReset, setChildReset] = useState(false);
              

              const sectionList = [
                { id: "3", sectionName: "UploadImage", data: uploadedImageList, ......... },
                { id: "1", sectionName: "InputFields", data: itemControlList,........ }
                .........
              ];
              
              const handleCallbackUploadImage = (childData) => {
                let arr = [];
                if (
                  childData &&
                  childData.dataArray &&
                  Object.keys(childData.dataArray).length > 0
                ) {
                  childData.dataArray.forEach((x) => {
                    arr.push(x);
                  });
                }
                setNewItemData((prevState) => ({
                  ...prevState,
                  uploadedImageList: arr,
                }));
                setValidateChild((prevState) => ({
                  ...prevState,
                  uploadedImage:
                    childData && childData.validationComplete
                      ? !childData.validationComplete
                      : false,
                }));
              };
              const handleCallbackItemAttribute = (childData) => {
                // code same as pervious function
              };
              
              
              const Save = () => {
                setSubmitted(true);
                setValidateChild((prevState) => ({
                  ...prevState,
                  uploadedImage: newItemData.uploadedImageList.length > 0 ? false : true,
                  itemAttribute: newItemData.itemAttributeList.length > 0 ? false : true,
                }));
                if (validateUpload()) {
                  // insert newItemData by API call
                }
              };
              const reset = () => {
                setSubmitted(false);
                setChildReset(true);
                setValidateChild((prevState) => ({
                  ...prevState,
                  uploadedImage: false,
                  itemAttribute: false, .....
                }));
              };
              return (
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  {sectionList.map((item, index) => (
                    <div className="row" key={index} style={{ padding: "2em" }}>
                      {item.sectionName === "UploadImage" ? (
                          <UploadImage
                            uploadImageOption={uploadImageOption}
                            data={item.data}
                            onParentCallback={handleCallbackUploadImage}
                            reset={childReset}
                            validateChild={validateChild.uploadedImage}
                          />
                      ) : null}
                      {item.sectionName === "InputFields" ? (
                        <>
                          {item.toDisplay ? (                
                              <FoodInputControl
                                data={item.data}
                                onParentCallback={handleCallbackItemAttribute}
                                reset={childReset}
                                validateChild={validateChild.itemAttribute}
                              />
                          ) : null}
                        </>
                      ) : null}
                       ...................// more child component          
                    </div>
                  ))}
                  <div className="row justify-content-center" style={{ marginTop: "1em" }}>
                    <div style={{ width: "6%" }}>
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-lg btn-success"
                        style={{
                          fontWeight: "normal",
                          fontSize: "medium",
                        }}
                        onClick={Save}
                      >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave} /> Save
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ width: "6%" }}>
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-lg btn-warning"
                        style={{
                          fontWeight: "normal",
                          fontSize: "medium",
                        }}
                        onClick={reset}
                      >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUndo} /> Clear
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }

I will pick FoodInputControl child function control to further explain the problem
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function FoodInputControl({
  data,
  onParentCallback,
  reset,
  validateChild,
}) {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [sectionData, setSectionData] = useState(data);
  const [controlDataList, setControlDataList] = useState([]);

  function initalControlData() {
    let arr = [];
    if (data) {
      data.forEach((x) => {
        arr.push({
          id: x.id,
          controlID: x.controlID,
          controlName: x.controlName,
          controlType: x.controlType,
          controlTextData:
            x.controlType === "Text" || x.controlType === "Date"
              ? x.data
              : null,
          controlSelID:
            x.controlType === "DropDown"
              ? x.dataSel.filter((row) => row.id === x.data)[0].id
              : null,
          controlSelValue:
            x.controlType === "DropDown"
              ? x.dataSel.filter((row) => row.id === x.data)[0].value
              : null,
        });
      });
    }
    setControlDataList(arr);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    initalControlData();
    if (reset) {
      setErrors({});
      setSubmitted(false);
      initalControlData();
      setSectionData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        data,
      }));
      console.log("Reset");
      console.log(sectionData);
      onParentCallback({ dataArray: null, validationComplete: true });
    }
    if (validateChild) {
      setSubmitted(true);
      validateControl();
      onParentCallback({ dataArray: controlDataList, validationComplete: false });
    }
  }, [reset, validateChild]);
  function validateControl() {
    let errCount = 0;
    const errCollection = {};
    controlDataList.forEach((x) => {
      if (x) {
        if (
          (x.controlType === "Text" || x.controlType === "Date") &&
          x.controlTextData === null
        ) {
          errCollection[x.controlName] = x.controlName;
          errCount++;
        }
        if (
          x.controlType === "DropDown" &&
          x.controlSelID === null &&
          x.controlSelValue === "--select--"
        ) {
          errCollection[x.controlName] = x.controlName;
          errCount++;
        }
        .................
      }
    });
    setErrors(errCollection);
  }
  const handleInputChange = (event, item) => {
    let row = controlDataList.filter((x) => x.id === item.id)[0];
    let rowIndex = controlDataList.findIndex((x) => x.id === item.id);
    row.controlTextData = event.target.value;
    controlDataList[rowIndex] = row;
    setControlDataList(controlDataList);
    if (errors && errors[item.controlName]) {
      delete errors[item.controlName];
      setErrors(errors);
    }
    
    onParentCallback({ dataArray: controlDataList, validationComplete: true }); true is set based on some calculation
  };
  const handleSelectChange = (event, item) => {
    let row = controlDataList.filter((x) => x.id === item.id)[0];
    let rowIndex = controlDataList.findIndex((x) => x.id === item.id);
    row.controlSelID = event.target.value;
    row.controlSelValue = item.dataSel.filter(
      (x) => x.id === Number(event.target.value)
    )[0].value;
    controlDataList[rowIndex] = row;
    setControlDataList(controlDataList);
    if (errors && errors[row.controlName]) {
      delete errors[row.controlName];
      setErrors(errors);
    }
    onParentCallback({ dataArray: controlDataList, validationComplete: true }); true is set based on some calculation
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="col-md-12"
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(4, 1fr)",
      }}
    >
      {sectionData && sectionData.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="input-group col-md-3 w-100"
          style={{ padding: "0.25em 1em" }}
        >
          {item.controlType === "Text" ? (
            <>
              <div className="input-group-prepend col-md-6">
                <label
                  className="input-group-text w-100"
                  htmlFor={`${item.controlType}-${index}`}
                >
                  {item.controlName}
                </label>
              </div>
              <input
                type="text"
                className={
                  submitted && errors[item.controlName]
                    ? "form-control is-invalid"
                    : "form-control"
                }
                id={`${item.controlType}-${index}`}
                defaultValue={item.data}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, item)}
              />
              {submitted && errors[item.controlName] && (
                <p> Required. </p>
              )}
            </>
          ) : null}
          // same for dropdown(select), date, checboxlist etc. 
          
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

The first problem is that FoodInputControl is loading twice. I am not sure why that is. see the image of console.log at the start of FoodInputControl.js file. On the first load i have sectionData array at 22 count and on the second it becomes an empty array. I am not sure why that is happening

second problem: when I clicks save in parent it triggers validation in all child component. The code is working as expected. Then when I hit reset I get an error
FoodInputControl.js:116 Uncaught 
TypeError: sectionData.map is not a function
at FoodInputControl (FoodInputControl.js:116:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)

3rd I was wondering if I am going about it the right way. I have a feeling, that I am making this more complicated than it should be. Any pointers on more efficient way of coding will be appreciated.
I was reading on ref hook should i be using ref hook to Triger child validation?
Thanks for reading my long post
